# Retrieve the source code of a url using pycurl and a port number?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, pycurl

Is there any way to retrieve the url source code and  store it in a string  ,provided that a particular port is defined in pycurl module so that it works for a proxy network.
platform - ubuntu or any other linux distro

Comment: show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: For most proxies, you need a proxy host name *and* a port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get source of url

```
from StringIO import StringIO    
import pycurl

url = 'http://www.google.com/'

storage = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
content = storage.getvalue()
print content
```